# Why toggle button function is fired even if I uncheck toggle?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-ngmodel

I have a toggle button. When it is ONLY checked, I want to call a function. 
The problem is it is also called when I uncheck it.
How can I fix that?

```js
    <ion-grid class="geoGrid">
          <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-label position="stacked" class="geoLabel"
                >Use current location</ion-label
              >
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="geoToggle">
              <ion-item lines="none">
                <ion-toggle
                  slot="start"
                  name="blueberry"
                  [(ngModel)]="isActive"
                  (ionChange)="getGeoLocation($event)"
                ></ion-toggle>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
```

function in .ts file:

```js
      getGeoLocation(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.checked);
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp: any) => {
          this.locationPermissionsDenied = false;
          this.geoLatitude = resp.coords.latitude;
          this.geoLongitude = resp.coords.longitude;
          const city = {
            isActive: this.isActive,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude
          };
          console.log(this.isActive);
          this.httpService.changeIsActive(this.isActive);
          this.httpService.changeCity(city);
        }).catch((error) => {
          alert('Error getting location ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
      }
```

Comment: Where do you verify if it is checked to call a function?

Comment: Add `if (!event.detail.checked) return;` in the beginning of `getGeoLocation`

Comment: @Powkachu i tried to verify it inside function but does not work. Any solutions?

Comment: @Powkachu tried and it does not work.

Comment: Whats is printed when you do `console.log(event.detail.checked);` ?

Comment: @Powkachu true when I check it and false when I uncheck it but it enters the function for some reason.

Comment: When you change the state of `ion-toggle`, it will always fire the `ionChange` event, so it will always call `getGeoLocation`. So you need to add `if (!event.detail.checked) return;` in the beginning of `getGeoLocation`.

Comment: Or you can also use `isActive` to know if it's checked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ion-toggle` has only `ionChange` method which fires when the toggle is changed whether it's checked or unchecked. What you can do is check inside your function if it's checked or uncheck and then process your rest of the code.

You have binded the toggle with `isActive` and you can use it like:

```
getGeoLocation(event) {
  if (isActive) {
    // rest of your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need some logic to see if the box is checked:

```
getGeoLocation(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.checked);
        if(event.detail.checked) {
            this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp: any) => {
            this.locationPermissionsDenied = false;
            this.geoLatitude = resp.coords.latitude;
            this.geoLongitude = resp.coords.longitude;
            const city = {
              isActive: this.isActive,
              latitude: this.geoLatitude,
              longitude: this.geoLongitude
            };
            console.log(this.isActive);
            this.httpService.changeIsActive(this.isActive);
            this.httpService.changeCity(city);
          }).catch((error) => {
            alert('Error getting location ' + JSON.stringify(error));
          });
       }
 }
```